# Conditional exception

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to write a function so that

```
try:
    a() or b()
except:
    raise Error
```

How can i accomplish this so that the function only raises an error if **both** statements fail?

Fail means that a or b throws an exception. a() and b() throws the same type of exception

I have tried using

```
try:
    a()
except:
    raise Error

try:
    b()
except:
    raise Error
```

But this is not the behavior i want. Don't mind the error type, it's just simplification

Comment: 1. Never use bare `except:`. 2. What does *"fail"* mean here? Exceptions? 3. What exceptions could be thrown by `a()` and/or `b()`? The same ones? Different ones? 4. If you want to deal with *both* throwing errors, you will probably have to use nested `try`s.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ty for your quick response. I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception thrown from `a()` will prevent `b()` from being called as you have written it. You will need to put both method calls in separate `try` blocks in order to check that both fail.

If you always want to call both `a()` and `b()` then you need the following:

```
fail_count = 0

try:
    a()
except:
    fail_count += 1

try:
    b()
except:
    fail_count += 1

if fail_count == 2:
    # Do stuff
```

If, however, you only want to call `b()` if `a()` fails, then this will work:

```
try:
    a()
except:
    try:
        b()
    except:
        # Both failed!
```

Comment: I should reiterate that this is example code. You *really* should be capturing specific exceptions (not using a catch-all as per this example).

Comment: This just looks like java, stacking try  excepts, not a good practice, data flow must keep going, stopped or handled but not one method at a time.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I would not say it's pretty but it gets the job done.

Comment: @DanielSanchez That isn't really a helpful critique of this answer. You're only effectively saying "The requirements are wrong".

Comment: @Phylogenesis, nope I was just saying that in my opinion is not a good practice to handle it like that although is working. But just my opinion :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez Okay, but sometimes requirements lead to this sort of pattern. Say you want to make a TCP socket connection. Maybe you want to try with IPv6 first and then fall back to IPv4. You only want to do something if both attempts fail (perhaps show something in the UI). There is very little way to handle this other than with nested `try` block.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, lets say you have a stack of 1000 calls.....and want to handle if just 700 of them fails....will you stack the trys? thats what i was talking about... how will you handle it?

Comment: @DanielSanchez No, you'd probably have something similar to my first example except wrapped in a loop. But in the end you're still wrapping each call in a `try` block. How else do you count the failures?

Comment: so...try's enclosed in a loop? And for your question, did you saw my answer?

Comment: @DanielSanchez I did, but your answer doesn't take dependencies into account (where the choice of whether to call a function or not depends on whether another function throws an exception).

Comment: @Phylogenesis that was not he was asking about, he just need to know if one (which one) or two failed then handle it. So i reiterate, for 2 is pretty ok, but for more is hellcode.